# strucutreMap Dependency injection is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap3

In my application i configured structuremap like

```
 public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
        #region Constructors and Destructors

        public DefaultRegistry() {
            Scan(
                scan => {
                    scan.Assembly("Eterp.Data.ErpCore");
                    scan.Assembly("Eterp.Data.Seed");
                    scan.Assembly("Eterp.Application.ErpCore");
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                });


            ForConcreteType<AclAuthorizationManager>().Configure.Ctor<IResourceOperationAppService>()
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And  i have class

```
public class AclAuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {
        private readonly IResourceOperationAppService _resourceOperationAppService;



        public AclAuthorizationManager(IResourceOperationAppService resourceOperationAppService)
        {
            _resourceOperationAppService = resourceOperationAppService;
        }

        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var isCurrentUserAuthorized = context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            return isCurrentUserAuthorized && _resourceOperationAppService.CanAccessResource(context.Action.FirstOrDefault().Value, context.Principal.Claims);
        }
    }
```

This class is custom claim authorization class using in my application, but when i exceuting the application,i am getting an error which related to lack of  parameter required by the constructor, ( This class has constructor with parameter type IResourceOperation). but i already configured  all the details  in structureMap . i am sure that my structuremap configuration is working 100% well expect the creation of this AclAuthorizationManager class.because i am able to to apply DI in other classes.

**What is wrong part in my code?**

Answer (score 0):

in my experience when you specify the type constructor must say that inherits from the interface.

Therefore, you should replace this line:

```
ForConcreteType<AclAuthorizationManager>().Configure.Ctor<IResourceOperationAppService>()
```

By:

```
ForConcreteType<AclAuthorizationManager>().Configure.Ctor<IResourceOperationAppService>().Is<ResourceOperationAppService>()
```

Where is the implementation ResourceOperationAppService IResourceOperationAppService.

Comment: actually the problem solved ,in my situation the construction of Authorization class handled by .Net run time,so it will not inject the dependency . In structure map , we don't need to inherit any interface to create an object of class.